# Implement OAuth2.0 in the web application

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

I have used various OAuth2.0 authentication based web application(facebook, twitter, quickbook, etc) and accessed their APIs for fetching data services. Now I am looking for developing an web based application which implements OAuth2.0 based authentication itself. User can create apps and get token and secret and other details. My programming language is Java. I could not find enough literature over the same.

I need some help in exploring the way to implement OAuth2.0 authentication or any specifications which can be implemented ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest working with Spring Security. It has [very good extension for oAuth 2.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/wiki/oauth2).

If you want an example in Java, based on Spring, have a look [here](https://github.com/OhadR/oAuth2-sample).

Then, when you want to implement all necessary flows, like 'create account', 'forgot password', etc - you can use [this project](https://github.com/OhadR/oAuth2-sample/tree/master/authentication-flows), that implements all these flows!

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at ApiFest OAuth20 project - https://github.com/apifest/apifest-oauth20.
It's written in Java and uses Netty as a server. As a storage, it currently uses Hazelcast(by default), MongoDB or Redis. Also, you can easily add another backend storage.You can see more about the project on http://apifest.com.
Good luck!

Comment: Could have been very nice. Too bad about the horrible code.